# I am trying to insert a VLOOKUP formula using VBA but it throws an error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to insert a VLOOKUP formula using VBA but I keep getting an error.

```
Sub CCC()
 Dim Lastrow As Long 'Used for the formulas
   Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B2").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\aNTHONY\[cLASS.xlsx]cLASS'!$B$2:$F$1048576,2,FALSE)"

Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Lastrow)

End Sub
```

But it throws an error at the line:

```
 Range("B2").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\aNTHONY\[cLASS.xlsx]cLASS'!$B$2:$F$1048576,2,FALSE)"
```

and the error is saying "application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: Range("B2").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\aNTHONY\[cLASS.xlsx]cLASS'!$B$2:$F$1048576

Comment: Looksl ike you're missing a parentheses in your `Formula` expression. You have an open/close parens for the `VLOOKUP` formula, but only an open parens for `IFERROR`.

Comment: What happens if you do: `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\aNTHONY\[cLASS.xlsx]cLASS'!$B$2:$F$1048576,2,FALSE))"`

Comment: @DavidZemens it will still throw the error because you are missing an argument.  cookiemonster: `Range("B2").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\aNTHONY\[cLASS.xlsx]cLASS'!$B$2:$F$1048576,2,FALSE),"""")"`

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Good catch @ScottCraner cheers.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now